# Footer appears in Content's area

Tags: html, css, reactjs, less, antd

I am using Next.js and antd's layout components to get a dashboard style page, using their `Layout` component. I have two issues with styling (CSS) here:

- `Footer` is sandwiched in `Content`: I am actually working on a derivative of the *fixed-sider example* from the [antd docs](https://codesandbox.io/s/wqlxkmw06w). I am getting `Footer` landed between the `Content` component. I suppose it's due to styling, but I am not able to figure it out. **What type of styling issue should I be looking for?**
- Scrolling behavior: Sidebar can not be be scrolled to its end if expanded fully. Instead, browser window scrollbar has to be scrolled to move completely through fixed sidebar's content. How to disable window's scrollbar (it looks ugly too with content's scrollbar)? **If not possible, how to make sidebar's scrolling smooth and independent from the browser window's?**

**I have reproduced the error [here in the CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/307rxxr9v6).**

[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this issue is happening due the way multiple `<Layout />` components and their children interact with each other when they have different heights. Child `Layout` and `Content` components seem to always (not 100% it's always) inherit height from their parent `Layout`, or at the very least always have a smaller height.

Currently, you have your Layout's setup like so (pseudocode):

```html
<Layout>
  <Layout restrictedHeight >
    <Layout inheritedRestrictedHeight>
      <Content inheritedRestrictedHeight >
        <div unrestrictedHeight />
      </Content> //Content "height" ends here
      <Footer fixedPosition /> //Always begins where Content ends
      //Div "height" ends here
    </Layout>
  </Layout>
</Layout>
```

Due to the way footer is implemented, in the DOM it is placed after the Content, but since the large div's DOM objects height is not restricted, it ends well bellow the Content container. This is why the `Footer` component appears to render in the middle of content.

The reason is this line:

```
<Layout hasSider={true} style={{ height: "100vh", marginTop: 64 }}>
```

You are setting the height property to 100vh meaning 100% view height, which is effectively just the current number of pixels available on the screen on the y-axis.

Instead of 100% view height you want your containing layout object to be the full size of all content on the page, even content that is off screen. To do this simply set height to `100%` rather than `100vh`:

```
<Layout hasSider={true} style={{ height: "100%", marginTop: 64 }}>
```

Edit:
This takes care of your double scroll bar issue as well.

***UPDATE AND ANSWER TO NONSCROLLING SIDEBAR***

I finally have another chance to look at this and this is where you need to give the `Sider` component a set height of what is showing on the screen.

The component is rendering to the DOM as a div with a height of the content contained inside it. To the browser, it doesn't care that part of it is off the screen because you are effectively telling the browser it's supposed to be that big.

In order to get the sidebar to scroll you need to limit the height to the size of that space (right bellow the nav bar to the bottom of the screen). To do this you need to calculate 100vh minus the size of the nav bar in the css/less for sidebar: `height: calc(~"100vh - 64px");` and make sure overflow-y is auto.

```
.sidebar {
  // fixed sider
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: calc(~"100vh - 64px");
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
}
```

Here is an updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/p5r1qqkj1x)

In the future, try to keep your questions to only one main question, it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, this explanation is beautiful. Q: How did you deduce this, and what do you imply by "not 100% it's always inherited height"? Also, could you please look into the second issue of janky/blocked scrolling in sidebar. Thank you!

Comment: I used to developer tools built into most browsers to figure out the sizes of the Layout components and their children. I found that each child Layout was smaller than it's parent regardless of what I set the height to in CSS. I only say I'm not 100% that's always the case because I have not tested it enough and don't know how the internals of Layout work exactly. As for the sidebar, it seemed to me that this solved it as well.

Comment: Ahh, I misread the question. I'm not sure about the sidebar and why it won't scroll.

Comment: you have been really helpful and precise. I have raised an issue with antd for Sider scrolling issue. If it's not CSS directly, I'd happily accept your answer. Till then, I'd prefer to keep this open.

Comment: Sure it works, and again awesome explanation. Also, I asked both the questions together, since I had a feeling that they could be related, that is, it was on purpose an attempt to put forth the complete status of my code. Thanks!

Comment: Sure it works, and again awesome explanation. Also, I asked both the questions together, since I had a feeling that they could be related, that is, it was on purpose an attempt to put forth the complete status of my code. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move footer down between line 119-120 and that should take care of it. This would put footer on same container as sidebar.

Comment: Hi @Ty T, it doesn't! Sider, being fixed too, sits on top of the Content and Footer areas.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I can't edit your script but after looking at it. I would suggest you to place:

```
<Footer style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            Ant Design ©2018 Created by Ant UED
          </Footer>
```

After the layout tag.

Comment: Hello @yaKay, that won't do (tried it). `Layout` component uses flex layout in antd, and so pulling Footer out is a different layout altogether which I don't want.